# Do que esse layout é composto?

Tags: android

Vi esse app e nessa tela tem umas divisões que parecem ter sido feitas com cardview, alguem pode dizer se realmente foi feito dessa forma ou como foi feito?

Outro detalhe é no final, tem um botão que pega toda largura da tela, ele tem duas funções, localizar uma foto ou tirar uma foto com a camera, como foi feito esse botão?

Existem componentes específicos para isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo Hugo, você mesmo mencionou os componentes. Foi usado provavelmente Card View. Porém também é possível conseguir isso em um layout com elevação.

Sobre o botão no final: Provavelmente também é um CardView que possui dois Image Buttons com backgrounds trasparentes e uma view para fazer aquele traço dividindo os botões.

Uma view nesse estilo:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/SUA_COR_AQUI"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
     />
```

As margens são para dar o efeito de a View estar afastada das bordas do card.